# Question about obtaining a bivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, bivariate-distributions

A random vector $X = (X_1 , X_2 ) \in R^2$ is distributed according to the bivariate normale distribution with mean vector $\mu_x = (0,0)$ and a covariance matrix

$$\Sigma_x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} .$$

I would like to know how it is possible to simulate an independent normal couples from a bivariate normal vector $Y$ with a mean vector $ \mu_y = (0 , 0 )$ and a covariance matrix

$$\Sigma_y = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 2 \\ 2 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$$ using the equality in distribution $Y \stackrel{d}=\Sigma_y^{1/2} X$.

What is the name of this method for sampling?

Comment: I do not know if that is a specific name for this sampling. The transformation is a "scale" transform (at least in univariate case).

Usually we have a uniform number generator. The simulated sample $X(\omega_1, \omega_2)$ is a realization - we simulate the uniform numbers $\omega_1, \omega_2$, and then put into the function $X$. The resulting sample will have the distribution of $X$. We can further put this sample in another function, say $Y = g(X)$ in distribution, and we can obtain a sample of $Y$ after the mapping.

Comment: @BGM What are the constraints on the function $Y$? is it possible for any function $Y$? Also, is it possible to sample from $Y$ using directly the normal $X$ without the need of $X$?

Comment: Technically speaking you need measurable function for it to be a random variable, but most of the function you met is measurable I guess. I do not understand the second statement. I will say again that usually you first have a random number generator, which generate according a certain distribution (usually uniform), then you use whatever algorithm you know on that.